# How can I create a relation with Neo4j on MRI?

Tags: ruby, neo4j

I want to use [neo4j](http://www.neo4j.org/) with MRI, and a gem called [`neo4j-cypher`](https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-cypher) is the only interface for MRI that I could find. This gem does not seem to be well documented, especially on how to create the relations. I can find documentation for similar gems, or for the Cypher language outside of the context of Ruby, but I cannot find one that shows how to create a relation with the gem neo4j-cypher. Can you demonstrate how to create a relation? Is there any tutorial for this gem that shows how to create the relation structure?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ruby drivers for MRI, see http://neo4j.org/drivers

The most advanced is neography from Max de Marzi, http://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography

which I would recommend to use.